# How should I keep my website hidden from the general public and give only a few people access to it?

Tags: spring, web, ip, information-hiding

I have a website, and I am planning for a pre-pilot release. I need to keep my website hidden from the general public and only can have access to a limited number of people (3-5 people ).

Currently, the website is hosted on the Oracle cloud

I need an alternative way for IP whitelisting

Comment: It is a problem statement of Networking rules. Check the options available in Oracle cloud to restrict ips/networks. I can tell about Google Cloud, but surely there is something similar in Oracle cloud also. Check the networking documentation.

Comment: the problem is that allowing people who don't have a static IP address

Comment: Normally these 3-5 people are from the team, so should be under some vpn. You may be able to allow that subnet. Else you need to put the website behind some authorization mechanism on temporary basis and only authenticated user will have access.

Comment: these 3-5 people are not from the same team . also I looking for without altering the website.